# Unable to get performance benefit from ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: android, multithreading, image, performance, threadpoolexecutor

I am downloading quite a number of images using  ThreadPoolExecutor. The android app's performance is excellent on a 10mbps connection and usually outmatches the results of similar data download on an iPad.

However when i run the same app on a faster internet connection (60mbps), the android app is unable to sync faster (takes 6 minutes) whereas iPad downloads everything in a minute.

I have had speed check on both the devices on either of the connections and got same results which means no issue with the pads. I had factory reset the devices in order to avoid any external app causing the trouble, tried optimizing the image downloads with Picasso, BitmapFactory etc but no luck.

I have Samsung Galaxy Tab S2(T173) with octa-core and 3GB RAM and iPad Air.

Is this something related to the processor limitations of android platform or am i missing something on the development end, please help... thanks in advance.

This is how i am using ThreadPoolExecutor.

```
int NUMBER_OF_CORES = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
               NUMBER_OF_CORES * 2,
               NUMBER_OF_CORES * 2,
               60L,
               TimeUnit.SECONDS,
               new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()
          );
 executor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);

 for (int i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) {
                 executor.execute(new ImageDownloader(context, i, new Handler(), imageUrl, diagram_names.get(i), null));
            }
```

And here's the ImageDownloader Class:

```
public class ImageDownloader implements Runnable {
int threadNo;
Handler handler;
String imageUrl;
public static final String TAG = "Image Downloader";
String imageName, calledFrom;
Activity applicationContext;
public ImageDownloader() {

}

public ImageDownloader(Activity applicationContext, int threadNo, Handler handler, String imageUrl, String imageName, String calledFrom) {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    this.threadNo = threadNo;
    this.handler = handler;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.imageName = imageName;
    this.calledFrom = calledFrom;
}

@Override
public void run() {
        if(CommonMethods.isNetworkAvailable(applicationContext))
            getBitmap(imageUrl, imageName);
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url, String imageName) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        saveImage(Picasso.with(applicationContext).load(url).get(), imageName, url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bitmap;
}

private void saveImage(Bitmap bmImg, String name) {
    if (bmImg != null) {
        try {
            File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString() + "/AppReader/saved_signature");

            // make the directory if it does not exist yet
            if (!myDir.exists()) {
                myDir.mkdirs();
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                Log.i("in save()", "after outputstream");
                DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = applicationContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
                int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
                Bitmap resizedBitmap = bmImg;
                resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You are probably missing something at the development end.  But unless you can show us the relevant parts of your code, we can only guess what that might be.

Comment: @StephenC: I have updated my question with relevant code information. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do some optimizations - e.g. use e.g. java.util.concurrent.Executors.newCachedThreadPool() - this is again ThreadPoolExecutor, but configured differently - see doc https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool() for more info

Also in your code above, it seems you try to write always to the same file (name argument is not used in saveImage), which is definitelly not ok, because its blocking, but I guess it's just copy/paste error.

And also it doesn't hurt if you move the "init" code - checks for directory exists, displayMetrics, etc to some other parts of the code, so they are not executed on every thread.

Then, you can also check whether the limiting factor is not the write speed to whatever getExternalStorageDirectory() points to on your device - e.g. your network might be really fast, but if your storage is slow ...

Comment: Using Executors.newCachedThreadPool() spawns all the thread at once. Thus i am getting OKHTTP error saying too many files open at a time, also certain threads are blocked and some rejected. This also freezes the application and requires killing the app. I could return custom threadpool in newCachedThreadPool() but then it works same as how i originally did it. Please suggest.

Comment: Tried other improvements suggested, did not found any notable difference but did improved the code. Also writing to external disk doesn't seem to be an issue here. Please suggest.

Comment: Oh, you are trying to download THAT many files simultaneously.... ok, then you definitelly can limit the pool to a more acceptable value - or... probably if you want to match/exceed your iPad performance - check how many simultaneous connections it opens and do the same or a little more (+1?)

Comment: Yeah, that's what i have been doing..but not able to get performance out of it. I'll be experimenting with threadpools more. Please suggest if you find any resolution.